# missing minute data from coinApi

Tags: python, cryptoapi, historical-db

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my coding or maybe I should rather ask CoinAPI this question directly. If I want to get some minute data from a coin, some data appears to be simply missing. In the picture with the output of my code you can see, that the data for the minute at 2018-05-31T23:42 is missing. Do you know a better site with historical crypto minute data?
This is my code:

```
import requests
symbol_id = 'BINANCE_SPOT_IOTA_USDT'
period_id = '1MIN'
limit = '5'
time_start='2018-05-31T23:40:00'
headers = {'X-CoinAPI-Key' : 'My CoinAPI-Key'}
response = requests.get(
f'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/ohlcv/{symbol_id}/history?period_id={period_id}&time_start={time_start}&limit={limit}',
headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CoinAPI provides an additional parameter called `period_id` which accepts the units `second/minute/hour/day/month/year`. Data can be requested by the period.

| period_id | parameter |
| --- | --- |
| Second | 1SEC, 2SEC, 3SEC, 4SEC, 5SEC, 6SEC, 10SEC, 15SEC, 20SEC, 30SEC |
| Minute | 1MIN, 2MIN, 3MIN, 4MIN, 5MIN, 6MIN, 10MIN, 15MIN, 20MIN, 30MIN |
| Hour | 1HRS, 2HRS, 3HRS, 4HRS, 6HRS, 8HRS, 12HRS |
| Day | 1DAY, 2DAY, 3DAY, 5DAY, 7DAY, 10DAY |
| Month | 1MTH, 2MTH, 3MTH, 4MTH, 6MTH |
| Year | 1YRS, 2YRS, 3YRS, 4YRS, 5YRS |

```py
import requests
url = 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/ohlcv/BTC/USD/history?period_id=1MIN&time_start=2016-01-01T00:00:00&period_id=1MIN'
headers = {'X-CoinAPI-Key' : '01E867A9-BB46-4A45-A1B4-BE140767040E'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

```
{
    "time_period_start": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "time_period_end": "2016-01-01T00:01:00.0000000Z",
    "time_open": "2016-01-01T00:00:16.0000000Z",
    "time_close": "2016-01-01T00:00:16.0000000Z",
    "price_open": 430.350000000,
    "price_high": 430.390000000,
    "price_low": 430.350000000,
    "price_close": 430.390000000,
    "volume_traded": 0.072700000,
    "trades_count": 4
  },
  {
    "time_period_start": "2016-01-01T00:01:00.0000000Z",
    "time_period_end": "2016-01-01T00:02:00.0000000Z",
    "time_open": "2016-01-01T00:01:01.1500000Z",
    "time_close": "2016-01-01T00:01:46.0000000Z",
    "price_open": 430.890000000,
    "price_high": 430.890000000,
    "price_low": 430.380000000,
    "price_close": 430.400000000,
    "volume_traded": 1.028431010,
    "trades_count": 7
  },
```

Comment: yeah, I used this parameter as you can see in my code.